# Trouble solving this differential equation: $x'=3(x-2)$, $x(0)=-1$.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the solution of the differential equation $x'=3(x-2)$ given an initial value condition of $x(0)=-1$.

This is my attempt:

$$x'=3(x-2) \iff \frac{dx}{dt} = 3(x-2) \iff \frac{dx}{x} - 2 = 3dt$$
$$\iff \int\bigg(\frac{dx}{x}\bigg)-2 = \int(3dt + c) \iff ln|x-2| = 3 + C$$
$$\iff |x-2| = e^3 e^{c_1} \iff |x-2| = e^3 c_2$$
$$|x-2| = e^3 C$$
$$|-3| = e^3 C \iff \frac{3}{e^3} = C$$

Plug back in:

$$|x-2|=e^3 C$$

Is what I have done correct?

Comment: You rather have $|x(t)-2|=e^{3t+C}$ giving $|x(t)-2|=e^C e^{3t}=Ke^{3t}$ with $K=e^C$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** What you have done is not correct. Observe that
$$
\int 3 \:dt= 3t+C, \quad C \, \text{is a constant}.
$$ Here you have
$$
\int\frac{dx}{x-2}=\int 3 \:dt \tag1
$$ or
$$
\ln|x-2|=3t+C
$$$$
x(t)-2=Ke^{3t}. \tag2
$$ You obtain $K$ by putting $t=0$ in $(2)$,
$$
x(0)-2=K
$$$$
-1-2=K.
$$ Then

> $$
> x(t)=2-3e^{3t}.
> $$

Answer (score 0):

$x^{'} (t) = 3(x (t)-2) ; \quad x(0)=-1 $

The differential equation can be written equiavalently as

$$ x^{'} (t) -3x(t)=-6$$

Now multiplying both sides of the above with the "integrating factor" $ e^{-3t}$ we obtain:

$$ x^{'} (t) e^{-3t} -3e^{-3t}x(t)= -6e^{-3t} $$

$$ (x(t) e^{-3t})^{'} = (2 e^{-3t})^{'} $$

Hence, $x(t)e^{-3t} = 2e^{-3t} +c$, where $c \in \mathbb R $ is a real parameter.

Plug in now $t=0 : \quad x(0)=2+c \Longrightarrow c=-3.$

Therefore, $ \boxed{ x(t)= -3e^{-3t} +2, \quad x \in \mathbb R }.$